# Unspecified error when sending multiple emails using a loop c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows form program i use to manage my business. I keep all customers details in the database linked inc. email addresses. I have a button that lets me send out an email to everyone that is on the mailing list (code below). But it crashes after sending a few emails with an unspecified error. I can't work out why? I need it to send out the same email to all the customers at once going from CustomerID40- CustomerID1425 Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if the code is messy. Thank you.
Error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
>
> HResult=0x80004005
>
> Message=Unspecified error
>
> Source=System.Data
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)
>
> at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
>
> at CourseworkDatabase.clsDBConnector.Connect() in
>   C:\Users\rep\OneDrive\Desktop\Repairs\ Repairs_Database\CourseworkDatabase\CourseworkDatabase\clsDBConnector.cs:line 18

### Code:

```
private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to send email to all customers?(check code)", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);​
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)​
    {
        DoButtonTask();​
    }​
}​​
private void DoButtonTask()
{
    for (int i = 40; i < 1425; i++)​ //40-1425 is customerID's
    {
        clsDBConnector dbConnector1 = new clsDBConnector();​
        OleDbDataReader dr1;​
        string sqlStr1;​
        dbConnector1.Connect();​
        sqlStr1 = " SELECT CustomerID, DateAdded, FullName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, SendOffersByEmail"​ +
            " FROM Customer" + ​
            " WHERE (CustomerID = " + i + ")";​
        dr1 = dbConnector1.DoSQL(sqlStr1);​
        string name = "";​
        string CustomerID = "";​
        string email = "";​
        string SendOffersBy_Email = "";​
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;​
        while (dr1.Read())
        {    ​
            CustomerID = CustomerID + Convert.ToString(dr1[0]);​
            name = name + dr1[2];​
            email = email + Convert.ToString(dr1[4]);​
            SendOffersBy_Email = SendOffersBy_Email + Convert.ToString(dr1[5]);​
        }​
        if (email == "na" || email == "na@na.co.uk" || email == "na@na.com" || email == "")​
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Customer " + CustomerID + " does not have an email linked.");​
        }​
        else
        {
            if (SendOffersBy_Email == "yes" || SendOffersBy_Email == "Yes")​
            {    ​
                try​
                {    ​
                    SendEmail(i, email, name);​
                }​
                catch (Exception ex)​
                {    ​
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());​
                }​
            }​
            else​
            {   ​
                //MessageBox.Show("Customer " + CustomerID + " does not accept emails.");​
            }​
        }​
    }​
    MessageBox.Show("Emails sent.");​
}​​

private void SendEmail(int i, string email, string name)​
{    ​​
    try​
    {    ​
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();​
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");​
        mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail");​
        mail.To.Add(email);​
        mail.Subject = "PRICE DROP!! Have your iPhone repaired today.";​
        mail.Body = "Hi " + name + ",\n" + ​
            "Our iPhone 7 and iPhone 8 series screen prices have now dropped in price!" + ​
            " Reply to this email to have your iPhone booked in for repair today - the prices may go back up! " + ​
            " All of our repairs come with our 6 months warranty and we can come to you." + ​
            "\n\nKind regards,\n Your Mobile Phone & Tablet Repair Specialist." + ​
            "\n\nTel: \nWebsite: \nEmail: " + ​
            "\nFacebook: " + ​
            "\n\n\n Don't want to recieve offers anymore? Just reply to this email to let us know and we will take you off our mailing system."​;​​

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;​
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail", "mypassword");​
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;​
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);​
        mail.Dispose();​
    }​
    catch (Exception ex)​
    {    ​
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());​
    }​​
}
```

Comment: why open and closed your db around 1385 times? open it at the start, itterate, and close.  Your AV maybe blocking it

Comment: @BugFinder oh right - I didn't even think of that. I will try moving the below outside the loop and try that. I'm not the most intermediate at programming so thank you. I think that's what you mean anyway? Ill try it later today.

clsDBConnector dbConnector1 = new clsDBConnector();​
                    OleDbDataReader dr1;​
                    string sqlStr1;​
                    dbConnector1.Connect();​

Comment: yep, try that see if the error goes away

Comment: another issue could be that the amount of active objects is limited; this burned me when i made a tool for outlook;
I ended up having to close and reopen outlook every 100 actions, to prevent the program from crashing on me

Comment: @BugFinder it is working perfectly now. Thank you for your help. Thank you ThisIsMe too.

Comment: Let me know if its better i delete this post or keep it up

Comment: @lewis if moving the opening out of the loop fixed it, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: yes post it as an answer i will tick it as answered, thank you. @BugFinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an obvious improvement to the code:

```
    for (int i = 40; i < 1425; i++)​ //40-1425 is customerID's
    {
        clsDBConnector dbConnector1 = new clsDBConnector();​
        OleDbDataReader dr1;​
        string sqlStr1;​
        dbConnector1.Connect();​ 
        ...
   }
```

This code opens your DB for every itteration, this adds overhead, and probably your antivirus is checking the file every time.

I would suggest move the connect outside the loop (and the close), so it becomes

```
clsDBConnector dbConnector1 = new clsDBConnector();​
OleDbDataReader dr1;​
string sqlStr1;​
dbConnector1.Connect();​
for (int i = 40; i < 1425; i++)​ //40-1425 is customerID's
{
   // process data
}
dbConnector1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Moved the DB retrieval in a separate function.

Made only one query getting all the data and put in a structure.

```
private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to send email to all customers?(check code)", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);​
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)​
    {
        DoButtonTask();​
    }​
}​​
private class Customer
{
    public string CustomerID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string SendOffersBy_Email {get; set;}     
}
private List<Customer> getCustomers(string query)
{
    List<Customer> output = new List<Customer>();
    try​
    {        
        clsDBConnector dbConnector1 = new clsDBConnector();​
        OleDbDataReader dr1;​
        dbConnector1.Connect();​

        dr1 = dbConnector1.DoSQL(query);

        while (dr1.Read())
        {   
            Customer c = new Customer();
            c.CustomerID = Convert.ToString(dr1[0]);
            c.Name = dr1[2];
            c.Email = Convert.ToString(dr1[4]);​
            c.SendOffersBy_Email = Convert.ToString(dr1[5]);​
            output.Add(c);
        }​
    ​}
    catch (Exception ex)​
    {    ​
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());​
    }​​
    finally
    {
        return output;
    }

}
private void DoButtonTask()
{
    int minCustomerID = 40;
    int maxCustomerID = 1425;
    string  sqlStr1 = "SELECT CustomerID, DateAdded, FullName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, SendOffersByEmail"​ +
        " FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID >= " + minCustomerID + " and CustomerID < " + maxCustomerID + ";" ;​

    List<Customer> aCustomers = getCustomers(sqlStr1);

    foreach (customer in aCustomers)
    {
        string email = customer.Email;
        if (email == "na" || email == "na@na.co.uk" || email == "na@na.com" || email == "")​
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Customer " + customer.CustomerID + " does not have an email linked.");​
        }​
        else
        {
            if (customer.SendOffersBy_Email == "yes" || customer.SendOffersBy_Email == "Yes")​
            {    
  ​             SendEmail(i, email, customer.Name);​
            }​
            else​
            {   ​
                //MessageBox.Show("Customer " + CustomerID + " does not accept emails.");​
            }​
        }​
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Emails sent.");​
}​​

private void SendEmail(int i, string email, string name)​
{    ​​
    try​
    {    ​
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();​
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");​
        mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail");​
        mail.To.Add(email);​
        mail.Subject = "PRICE DROP!! Have your iPhone repaired today.";​
        mail.Body = "Hi " + name + ",\n" + ​
            "Our iPhone 7 and iPhone 8 series screen prices have now dropped in price!" + ​
            " Reply to this email to have your iPhone booked in for repair today - the prices may go back up! " + ​
            " All of our repairs come with our 6 months warranty and we can come to you." + ​
            "\n\nKind regards,\n Your Mobile Phone & Tablet Repair Specialist." + ​
            "\n\nTel: \nWebsite: \nEmail: " + ​
            "\nFacebook: " + ​
            "\n\n\n Don't want to recieve offers anymore? Just reply to this email to let us know and we will take you off our mailing system."​;​​

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;​
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail", "mypassword");​
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;​
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);​
        mail.Dispose();​
    }​
    catch (Exception ex)​
    {    ​
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());​
    }​​
}
```